# Stretch video to full screen in a SurfaceView extension

Tags: android, android-widget

I have created a widget that is an extension of `SurfaceView` (very similar to [VideoView](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/VideoView.java)) and I am working on a feature to stretch the video fully across the device screen when certain action is taken. I've looked at `onMeasure` function of `VideoView` and re-wrote it this way:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    if (mStretchVideo) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    } else {
        int width = getDefaultSize(mVideoWidth, widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = getDefaultSize(mVideoHeight, heightMeasureSpec);
        if (mVideoWidth > 0 && mVideoHeight > 0) {
            if (mVideoWidth * height > width * mVideoHeight) {
                height = width * mVideoHeight / mVideoWidth;
            } else if (mVideoWidth * height < width * mVideoHeight) {
                width = height * mVideoWidth / mVideoHeight;
            }
        }
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }
}
```

This seems to work fine if I completely stop the video and start playing again. Now I am trying to force the refresh of this `SurfaceView` after setting the stretch flag so that the video gets stretched while it is playing, but I couldn't figure out how to force a refresh on `SurfaceView`. I tried `android.view.View.invalidate()`, `android.view.View.refreshDrawableState()` and calling `android.view.View.measure(int, int)` directly with different combinations but did not get any success. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

No need of code to play video in full screen mode

#### Apply the following layout format over the xml containing the videoview it will for sure will play the video in full screen mode. as it is running mine :) Hope it helps

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
   <VideoView android:id="@+id/myvideoview"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </VideoView>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: How can this XML be applied to a video that is already playing covering only part of the screen? This is the OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the `measure` method of the `SurfaceView` from the Activity like this:

```
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
    int childWidthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(display.getWidth(),
            MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    int childHeightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(display.getHeight(),
            MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    surfaceView.measure(childWidthMeasureSpec, childHeightMeasureSpec);
```

Answer (score 0):

Javanator is the correct answer. There is no need for additional code. Make sure your video view looks like this

```
 <VideoView android:id="@+id/myvideoview"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

Comment: why repeating the same answer ?